# ListBox shows System.Collection.ArrayList

Tags: c#, asp.net, arraylist, listbox

i have a listbox on one page which carries the items in the listbox to another list box on another page, but when the second listbox shows "System.Collection.ArrayList".

Page1:

```
protected void btnCheckout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Session["Name"] = NameText.Text;
    Session["PhoneNumber"] = PhoneTextBox.Text;
    Session["Address"] = AddressText.Text;
    Session["Email"] = emailText.Text;
    Session["City"] = cityTextBox.Text;
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < ItemListBox.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (ItemListBox.Items[i].Selected == true)
        {
            al.Add(ItemListBox.Items[i].Value);
        }
    }
    Session["selectedValues"] = al;
    Response.Redirect("Invoice.aspx");

}
```

Page2:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string phoneNumber = (string)(Session["PhoneNumber"]);
    string homeAddress = (string)(Session["Address"]);
    string name = (string)(Session["Name"]);
    string email = (string)(Session["Email"]);
    string city = (string)(Session["City"]);
    phoneLabel.Text = phoneNumber;
    addressLabel.Text = homeAddress;
    nameLabel.Text = name;
    emailLabel.Text = email;
    cityLabel.Text = city;
    invoiceListBox.Items.Add(Session["selectedValues"].ToString());
}
```

All other label session do work, it is only the listbox that does not work

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `Session["selectedValues"].ToString()`?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're adding the collection's toString() result (a string) as a single item.

Try `.AddRange` instead

Comment: He is also not adding the arraylist but a string: `Session["selectedValues"].ToString()`

Comment: Oh right, forgot about the .toString. I'll edit.

Comment: i get an error, i entered: 
invoiceListBox.Items.AddRange(Session["selectedValues"].ToString());

Comment: Remove the .toString() from that

Comment: invoiceListBox.Items.AddRange(Session["selectedValues"]);

^ what i have now and i still get an error and i also tried .Equals, but did not work

Comment: You need to cast Session["SelectedValues"] back into its proper type, since Session returns object. Items.AddRange( (ArrayList) Session["SelectedValues"]);

Comment: invoiceListBox.Items.AddRange((ArrayList)Session["SelectedValues"]);

^still getting an error, i added Using System.Collection;

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: "The best overloaded match for "system........." has some invalid arugments"

Comment: LOL this is an online debugger!

Answer (score 0):

Since all objects stored in a `Session` of type `object`, you need to cast them back to their original types before you can access their properties. This should give you an idea how it could be done. The key here is `ArrayList al = Session["selectedValues"] as ArrayList;`

```
ArrayList al = Session["selectedValues"] as ArrayList;

if(al != null)
{
    foreach(var item in al)
    {
        invoiceListBox.Items.Add(new ListItem {Value = item.toString(), Text = item.toString()});
    }
}
```

**Added**
Here is a working sample.

**default.aspx**

```
Phone Number: <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhoneNumber" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:ListBox ID="ItemListBox" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">One</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Two</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">Three</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">Four</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:ListBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <a href="page2.aspx">Page 2</a>
```

**default.aspx.cs**

```
namespace SO15888490
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["PhoneNumber"] = txtPhoneNumber.Text;

            ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

            for (int i = 0; i < ItemListBox.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ItemListBox.Items[i].Selected == true)
                {
                    al.Add(ItemListBox.Items[i].Value);
                }
            }

            Session["ItemsList"] = al;
        }

    }
```

**page2.aspx**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Phone Number: <asp:Literal ID="litPhoneNumber" runat="server" />
        <br />
        Selected Items<br />
        <asp:Literal ID="litItemsList" runat="server" />
        <br />
        <a href="Default.aspx">Back to default.aspx</a>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
}
```

**page2.aspx.cs**

```
namespace SO15888490 {
    public partial class page2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            litPhoneNumber.Text = (string)Session["PhoneNumber"];

            ArrayList al = Session["ItemsList"] as ArrayList;
            if (al != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in al)
                {
                    litItemsList.Text += item.ToString() + "<br/>";
                }
            }
        }
    } }
```

Comment: I have tried this, it shows no errors, but it does not work for me

Comment: Does `Session["selectedValues"] as ArrayList` return an `ArrayList` or `null`? If `ArrayList` what are it's contents? Are your values contained within it? Set a breakmark and look at it in the debugger.

Comment: i would say null, because nothing really happens,

Comment: Why is the ArrayList not being stored in the Session?

Comment: the code you have provided, is inteded for the second listbox?

Comment: The code I included goes in Page2 and replaces `invoiceListBox.Items.Add(Session["selectedValues"].ToString());`

Comment: yes i have replaced that, nothing happens. would like me to email you my website? because I would like a solution asap

Comment: @user2246454 - I have updated my answer with a working sample.